# How can I make a UIKeyCommand with the return/enter key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiresponder, uikeycommand

I'd like to make a `UIKeyCommand` that uses only the `[return]` key. So far I've tried:

```
UIKeyCommand *selectCommand = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"\n" modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(chooseSelection:)];
```

There's no global constant for the enter key, like there is for up, down, left, right, and escape (from `UIResponder.h`):

```
// These are pre-defined constants for use with the input property of UIKeyCommand objects.
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIKeyInputUpArrow         NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIKeyInputDownArrow       NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIKeyInputLeftArrow       NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIKeyInputRightArrow      NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIKeyInputEscape          NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Is there anything else I could try to capture the return/enter key?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Using `@"\r"` for carriage return instead of `@"\n"` for newline should work.

Comment: You probably want `\r` over `\n`.